# Homotopy of orthogonal groups in the unstable range

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

We fix an integer $n$ and consider the stabilization map $O(n)\to O$.
Using rational methods one can easily check that the map
$\pi_{4i-1}(O(n))\to \pi_{4i-1}(O)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ vanishes for sufficiently large $i$. Is a similar fact known for the map
$$\pi_{8i}(O(n))\to \pi_{8i}(O)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\ ?$$

Comment: Section 1 of the paper http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/levsph.pdf contains a similar result for $SO$. Perhaps the argument there works for $O$ also?

Comment: @MarkGrant: I am not sure if the paper of Levine contains a similar result, he seems to be talking about the (meta)stable range (i.e. something like $4i=n$ or $4i=n-1$). The question, however, seems to be talking about $i$ much larger than $n$, i.e. much above the stable range.

Comment: If $i$ is odd, then $\pi_{4i}(O)=0$, so I assume $i$ should be even in the question?

Comment: Ok, here is some numerical example in the first non-trivial case. I used tables from Kervaire's "Some unstable homotopy groups of Lie groups" and wrote out the stabilization sequences. The negative piece is that $\pi_8(SO(8))\to\pi_8(SO(9))$ and $\pi_8(SO(9))\to\pi_8(SO(10))$ are both surjective, where the last one is the stable value $\pi_8(SO)$. On the plus side,  $\pi_8(SO(5))=0$, so that map is trivial. I am not exactly sure about the $\pi_8(SO(6))=\mathbb{Z}/24$, but it seems the map $\pi_8(SO(6))\to\pi_8(SO(10))$ is also 0.

Comment: Some further negative information from Kervaire's paper: the exact sequence in II.10 implies a surjection $\pi_{8s}(SO(8s-i))\to\pi_{8s}(SO)$ for $s\geq 2$ and $i\leq 6$. So $8i-6\geq n$ would be necessary for vanishing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. In fact, for all sufficiently large n the maps $\pi_{8i}(O(n)) \to \pi_{8i}(O) \cong \Bbb Z/2$ are surjective for all $i$.

One possible tool for proving this has to do with $v_1$-periodic homotopy theory. For sufficiently large $d$, the mod-2 Moore space $W = \Sigma^{d-1} \Bbb{RP}^2$, which is the cofiber of a degree-2 map $S^d \to S^d$, has a certain type of "periodic" self-map $\Sigma^8 W \to W$. Any $2$-torsion element $\alpha \in \pi_{d+k} X$ extends from a map $S^{d+k} \to X$ to a map $\Sigma^k W \to X$, and we can precompose to get maps $\Sigma^{8+k} W \to X$ which determine a new $2$-torsion element $\alpha' \in \pi_{d+k+8} X$.

It so happens that, in the case of the orthogonal group $O$, this construction $\alpha \mapsto \alpha'$ gives an isomorphism $\pi_{8i} O \to \pi_{8i+8} O$, despite the possible indeterminacy in these definitions. Therefore, if one of these classes lifts to $\pi_{8i} O(n)$ and $i$ is bigger than $d$, the next one lifts to $\pi_{8i+8} O(n)$.